# Ansible AWX Operator deployment in K8S - Does it scale up the pods automatically if it needs to run several tasks over huge inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I could not find this in the AWX Operator documentation in Github.
We have several hundreds of servers in the inventory and we may run several templates in parallel.

I am trying to see if the AWX Deployment is sized properly for a huge/heavy workload.
will the PODs scale up automatically as per the workload being thrown at AWX? I don't think a HPA is created as part of AWX deployment through Operator.

Comment: The AWX deployment contains a web service and an optional database for the workloads. Neither of these are used for the runners as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

The ansible-awx operator does not provide HPA. I have it installed and the operator does not provide it.

You can check this here:

https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator/tree/devel/roles/installer/templates